# How to take many HTML tag as a javascript variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a variable with HTML and CSS value . How Can I add another HTML element inside a `<span >` element. Like if I want to take a `<a>` element inside a `<span>` element with different class?

```
var newSpan = $("<span></span>", {
    title: "Double Click to Edit Groups Name",
    id:     "myInstance2",
    style:"display:none; float:left;",
    text: "Unnamed Group",
    class: "title-span"
})
```

Comment: Just as a semantic note, you'd technically be adding a child `element` to the `span` `element`. A `tag` specifically refers to the HTML markup that defines either the beginning or ending of a representation of that `element` in HTML.

Comment: `Var newSpan` supposed to be `var newSpan`

Comment: Can you Give me Example ? I am poor in javascripts . just trying to modify with little Knowledge @Joey

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can append content to that element:

```
newSpan.append("<a href='' class='fred'></a>");
```

http://api.jquery.com/append/